# Is there a way to fix this error when going from web browser on a PC to the web browser on a phone?

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser

I'm working on a web app that, for the most part, looks fine on both a PC and a phone. However, if I have a dropdown list, the fonts are normal on a PC, but on a mobile browser, the items are super enlarged. I'm not doing anything too fancy in the background. I'm just wondering if there is a way to fix this? The "Select Recommendations" is the dropdown list.
[image]

The CSS is:

```
<style>
    ul,li { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
    .label { color:#000; font-size:16px;}
    .ms-options-wrap > .ms-options {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 1.2em; (I tried different px and % as well...it only changes it on the PC web browser. Mobile browser is still enlarged)
    }
    label{
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        color: #555 !important;
    }

    </style>
```

Comment: Right click on large element and inspect it and look for the font-size from where is got the font size! also you can assign the new font size for that element using CSS `element{font-size: 10px !important;` and you're welcome.

Comment: I tried what you said and it will affect the font size on a standard PC browser, but on a mobile browser (Android Chrome) it's still enlarged like in the picture.

Comment: Could you share html css codes?

Comment: Does it have the same effect on a PC when you reduce the screen size to a similar resolution as the tested Android phone?

Comment: I added the CSS for that part. As noted, it only seems to affect the display on the PC browser making it smaller or larger, but on the mobile browser, it's still super enlarged.

Comment: So please share your codes. and let me to check it for you.

Comment: I don't think I can share the entire code. It's a combined 4,371 lines of code across 5 files. However, I'll see if I can make a very small sample that shows the same problem and upload that code. I've had this problem occur several times and ignored it in the past, but currently, it is too problematic to ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears this is strictly a bug with Android Chrome. I've tested it under Safari on an iPad and using Firefox on an Android phone. It also works with Firefox and Edge on a PC. So I'll just close this for now. Android Chrome... *insert eyeroll emoji*